# How to add an xml-stylesheet link immediately after the 'open' xml tag on the rss2 feed?

Tags: rss

In order to style my rss2 feed, I would like to add the following content after the "open" xml tag:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="path/to/rss.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
```

So, the start of the document would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="path/to/rss.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
```

It seems like none of the hooks listed in the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) (ex = rss2_head) add content to the spot I need.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

There is no hook in the template. See `wp-includes/feed-rss2.php`:

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="'.get_option('blog_charset').'"?'.'>'; ?>

<rss version="2.0"
```

You have to replace the template with a complete new one. The template is loaded on the action `do_feed_rss2`. From `wp-includes/default-filters.php`:

```
add_action( 'do_feed_rss2', 'do_feed_rss2', 10, 1 );
```

Now you can remove the original action and add your own:

```
remove_action( 'do_feed_rss2', 'do_feed_rss2' );
add_action( 'do_feed_rss2', 'wpse_119139_feed_rss2', 10, 1 );

function wpse_119139_feed_rss2( $for_comments ) 
{
    if ( $for_comments )
        load_template( 'path_to_custom_comment_feed_template' );
    else
        load_template( 'path_to_custom_regular_feed_template' );
}
```